# Does the following proof work for (a special case of) the deduction theorem?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am interested in showing that $\{P\} \vdash Q$ if and only if $\vdash P \to Q$. This is a limited version of the deduction theorem where the "background" set of assumptions $\Delta$ happens to be empty.

The typical proof of the forward/"only if" direction is by induction. However, I am wondering if a proof like the following could also work. A few notes about my "proof system" before I give the attempted proof. My real interest in the deduction theorem is to try to better understand the material implication. So I don't want to "bake in" a meaning for "$\to$" by giving axioms that are suggestive. This leads to:

- I think I want to be working in a Hilbertian system, rather than a natural deduction system (which "bakes in" too much meaning into "$\to$"). This seems to work out since the deduction theorem isn't interesting in a natural deduction system anyway(?).
- I want to define "$P \to Q$" as a shorthand for "$\lnot P \lor Q$", rather than by directly giving axioms for "$\to$" that are suggestive of it having something to do with deduction.

With that out of the way, here is my attempted proof (I'll just do the forward/"only if" direction):

> **Attempted proof.** Suppose $\{P\} \vdash Q$. We have two cases, $P$ or $\lnot P$. If $P$, then since $\{P\} \vdash Q$ we have $Q$, so we have $\lnot P \lor Q$. On the other hand, if $\lnot P$ then we immediately have $\lnot P \lor Q$. In either case we have shown $\lnot P \lor Q$ so we are done.

A few questions I have about this:

- Does the above proof actually work?
- Am I essentially giving a semantic proof of the deduction theorem? If so, am I relying on soundness and/or completeness?
- I realize I am not exactly working inside the system/kind of cavalier about whether I am inside or outside the system. This is partly because I don't really have a system I am working with (as I explained above), and partly because I am not entirely sure what I am doing. But can this proof be turned into a more formal proof? If the proof can't be formalized, why not/what goes wrong?
- If the above proof works, why is the proof typically given using induction?

Comment: (1) No, because (2) yes, this is a semantic proof, and you are relying on both soundness and completeness. (3) In order to give a correct proof, you need to use the definition of $\vdash$, which involves all the gory details of the proof system. You need to somehow transform an arbitrary proof of Q from hypothesis P into a proof of $\lnot P\vee Q$ from no hypotheses. All you have to work with is the inductive structure of proofs, which is why proofs like this usually proceed by induction. If this answers your question, I can expand it into an answer.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, your strategy is limited to so-called Classica Logic, were Excluded Middle $P \lor \lnot P$ and the equivalence between $P \to Q$ and $\lnot P \lor Q$ hold.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks! It does mostly answer the question. I'm confused by your "No" to (1) though; doesn't a semantic proof still work? In other words, couldn't one hypothetically *not* prove the deduction theorem in the usual way, and instead prove soundness and completeness, and then use those to prove the deduction theorem?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I'm happy to work in classical logic.

Comment: @riceissa - but what I'm saying is the "standard" induction proof works also for other Logics...

Comment: Oh, certainly: if you can use soundness and completeness, then your proof works. But there's a danger of circularity: usually the deduction theorem is a component in the proof of the completeness theorem.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah, thanks, I now see what you mean and why that is one reason the induction proof is preferred.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks, I think that clears up everything for me (and just to be clear, while the deduction theorem is usually used in the proof of the completeness theorem, there are also other ways to prove completeness that don't rely on the deduction theorem?) I'd be happy to accept an answer pointing to this comment thread (or expanded version as you said in your original comment).